# Jquery простой таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как заставить таймер работать?

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var _Seconds = $('.seconds').text();
        if(_Seconds == 0)
        {
            alert('End!');
        } else {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $('.seconds').text(_Seconds - 1);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Может сделать, чтобы `_Seconds` изменялась внутри цикла? (или вообще убрать эту переменную, чтобы число секунд всегда получалось из `$('.seconds')`)

Comment: Непринциально, лишь бы работал таймер)

Comment: А, ещё, самое важное: нужно вместо `setTimeout` использовать [`setInterval`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: @diraria, разве есть разница что использовать?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ну, казалось бы, `setInterval` здесь больше подходит

Comment: @diraria, да, пожалуй, и выглядит изящнее)

Comment: @ГромСупиев если ответ помог решить вашу проблемы, вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним

Answer (score 2):

Такие таймеры легче делать через `setInterval()`, а вы запускаете `setTimeout()` лишь единожды.

А ошибка у вас, собственно, в том, что ваше условие никогда не выведет `alert()`, так как при описании условия `_Seconds` не будет равно `0`, и, повторюсь, `setTimeout()` срабатывать будет только 1 раз.

```js
var _Seconds = $('.seconds').text(),
  int;
int = setInterval(function() { // запускаем интервал
  if (_Seconds > 0) {
    _Seconds--; // вычитаем 1
    $('.seconds').text(_Seconds); // выводим получившееся значение в блок
  } else {
    clearInterval(int); // очищаем интервал, чтобы он не продолжал работу при _Seconds = 0
    alert('End!');
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seconds">10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Через `setTimeout`:

```js
const time = $('.seconds');
  
timerDecrement();

function timerDecrement() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const newTime = time.text() - 1;
    
    time.text(newTime);
    
    if(newTime > 0) timerDecrement();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="seconds">20</span>
```

Альтернативный вариант через `setInterval`, как советует diraria:

```js
const time = $('.seconds');
  intervalId = setInterval(timerDecrement, 1000);

function timerDecrement() {
  const newTime = time.text() - 1;

  time.text(newTime);

  if(newTime === 0) clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="seconds">20</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с рекурсивным `setTimeout`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sec = $('.seconds');
  var secVal = parseInt(sec.text());

  var timer = setTimeout(function tick() {
    if (secVal > 0) {
      sec.text(--secVal);
      timer = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.seconds {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="seconds">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант с редиректом на нужный урл, использую для уведомление после регистрации, с возвратом на главную.

```js
var box = $('.timer_replace'),
            text = box.html(),
            second = box.data('second')+1,
        int;
        int = setInterval(function() {
            second--;
            if (second > 0) {
                box.html(text+' '+second);
            } else {
                window.location.replace("/");
                clearInterval(int);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a class="timer_replace" data-second="5" href="/">На главную</a></div>
```